# Join statement with two different tables with similar but different data/keys

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I'm trying to do a join on two tables where one table has a clean primary key, while the other table has the same primary key data, but with extra characters.

Is there a way to do a match for the two columns as the result? Even though they're different in some regards?

```sql
select tbl1.cd, tbl1.nm, tbl1.vend_typ_id, tbl2.uidy, tbl2.addr_l1, tbl2.addr_l2, tbl2.addr_city, tbl2.addr_ctry, tbl2.addr_nm, tbl2.addr_stae, tbl2.addr_zpcd

from table1 tbl1
inner join table2 tbl2 on tbl1.cd = tbl2.uidy
```

Table 1 primary key data:

C000001628

C000001629

C000000208

C000000732

Table 2 primary key data:

&4025&1250&C000001628&*&P

&4025&1250&C000001629&*&P

&4025&1250&C000000208&*&P

&4025&1250&C000000732&*&P

The data isn't always like this either. Can I just have results of a "like" match?

Answer (score 0):

It is syntactically valid to say

```
inner join table2 tbl2 on tbl2.uidy like '%' || tbl1.cd || '%'
```

That's going to prevent Oracle from using the primary key on `table1` which may result in really poor query performance.  Depending on what, exactly, you mean by "the data isn't always like this either", it would be more efficient if you could write an expression to parse the `tbl2.uidy` value to extract the `tbl1.cd` because you could then create a function-based index on that expression.